# HTML button with different output onclick using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following setup - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvjmLv?editors=100 and am trying to output text depending on which button is clicked

```
<div class="question">
  <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">2</button>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">5</button>
  <button class="right-answer" type="button">6</button>
  <button class="wrong-answer" type="button">10</button>

  <script>
    var text;
    var wrongAnswer = document.getElementsByClassName("wrongAnswer").addEventListener("click");
    var rightAnswer = document.getElementsByClassName("rightAnswer").addEventListener("click");

    if (wrongAnswer) {
          text = "Incorrect!";
          text = "Wrong!";
          text = "Try Again!";
    }
    if (rightAnswer) {
        text = "Correct!";
    }               
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = text;
  </script>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
```

If the user selects the wrong answer, it should either read `Wrong!`, `Incorrect!` or `Try Again!` (without repeating the same text output if their next guess is also wrong)

If they get the answer right, it should just simply read `Correct!`

As I'm fairly new to JavaScript, I feel as though I'm a little bit off with my solution and was wanting to know how can I make this function work?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, one problem is that you assign a different value to `text` three times in a row. It's overwritten whenever a new value is assigned, so "Incorrect!" gets replaced with "Wrong!" and so on.

Comment: Please post your code.. not just a link to codepen

Comment: I remember just starting out - sometimes it feels like there's an unwritten rulebook that everyone has except you. Here's a fork of your codepen that walks you through the right approach to what you're trying to do: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjmMBo. I've added it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest and fastest way to get the result you want is by adding `onclick`-eventhandlers to your buttons.

```
<button onclick="somefunction()"></button>
```

After that you can easily handle what should happen after that click.

In your case I would check what's in the class attribute of the button you clicked.
By doing this you can print the results to your #answer-container.

With a simple array and a global variable of which index is next you can output different "false"-messages.

```js
var _i = 0;
var _wrongs = ['Incorrect!', 'Wrong!', 'Try Again!'];

function showResult(b) {
  var res = document.getElementById('answer');
  if (b.classList.contains('right-answer')) {
    res.innerHTML = 'Correct'
  } else {
    res.innerHTML = _wrongs[_i];
    _i = _i > 1 ? 0 : _i + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" onclick="showResult(this)">2</button>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" onclick="showResult(this)">5</button>
  <button class="right-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">6</button>
  <button class="wrong-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">10</button>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
```

[Demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doWLow)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple things that you need to do:

1. You do not have a separate click handler function defined.
2. You need to properly add the event function to the `addEventListener` call.
3. You cannot attach an event to multiple elements at once. You need to loop over them.
4. Why do you have two different classes? i.e. `'wrongAnswer'` and `'wrong-answer'`? Please make sure that you stick with one convention.

I added an `onReady()` to wait for the DOM to load before accessing and adding listeners to the elements.

### Addition Information

Below, I have wrapped the `document.getElementsByClassName(className)` call with `[].slice.call(scope, [begin[, end]])` because the result of `getElementsByClassName` is a `NodeList`. You cannot treat a list like an array in JavaScript. Since I used `Array.prototype.forEach` to loop over the elements, they needed to transformed into an array. This is simply syntactic sugar in order to make the code look more aesthetically pleasing and readable.

This could have easily been accomplished with a for-loop:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("rightAnswer");
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var el = nodes[i];
    el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
```

### Code

```js
var wrongTextArr = ['Try Again!', 'Wrong!', 'Incorrect!'];
var guesses = 0;

onReady(function() {
  // Set the number of guesses equal to the number of questions - 1.
  guesses = document.querySelectorAll('.question button').length - 1;
  
  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('wrongAnswer')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  });

  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('rightAnswer')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  });
});

function clickHandler(e) {
  var text = '';
  var target = e.target;
  var targetClass = target.className;
  
  if (guesses < 1) {
    text = 'You have reached the max number of attempts!';
  } else if (targetClass === 'wrongAnswer') {
    text = wrongTextArr[--guesses]; // Decrement guesses.
  } else if (targetClass === 'rightAnswer') {
    text = 'Correct!';
  } else {
    text = 'Unexpected Error!';
  }
  
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = text;
}


function onReady(callback) {
  var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
      window.clearInterval(intervalID);
      callback.call(this);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">2</button>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">5</button>
  <button class="rightAnswer" type="button">6</button>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">10</button>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
```

---

In the code above, I tried not to stray too far away from your original code, I just simply pointed out things that made your code not work and fix them with the minimalist amount of effort. Here is my solution that I would go with.

```js
var wrongTextArr = ['Try Again!', 'Wrong!', 'Incorrect!'];
var guesses = 0;

onReady(function() {
  // Set the number of guesses equal to the number of questions - 1.
  guesses = document.querySelectorAll('.question button').length - 1;
  addEventListeners('button[class$="Answer"]', 'click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = getText(e.target.className.split());
  });
});

function getText(classList) {
  if (guesses < 1) {
    return 'You have reached the max number of attempts!';
  } else if (classList.indexOf('wrongAnswer') > -1) {
    return wrongTextArr[--guesses]; // Decrement guesses.
  } else if (classList.indexOf('rightAnswer') > -1) {
    return 'Correct!';
  } else {
    return 'Unexpected Error!';
  }
}

// Generic functions.
function addEventListeners(selector, event, listenerFn) {
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener(event, listenerFn);
  });
}
function onReady(callback) {
  var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
      window.clearInterval(intervalID);
      callback.call(this);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">2</button>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">5</button>
  <button class="rightAnswer" type="button">6</button>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">10</button>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `[].slice` and `.call` are definitely going to be confusing topics for someone new to JS - consider explaining them, or providing some documentation. Also, `.querySelectorAll` will work better than two `.getElementsByClassName` if you're using the same event handler anyway.

Comment: @user1752759: Please do not violate the integrity of your original code. You should have forked it instead of integrating my suggestions into it. Can you include the original code you provided in your CodePen in your question? Thanks.

Comment: @Oka: Thanks for the suggestion. I added clarification.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Polywhirl, it seems to be working.  Is there a way to also output different text using your solution such as the one provided by #Werner and is there any benefits of using your solution over his?

Comment: Looks good @Mr.Polywhirl however, I noticed that if on your fourth try when selecting the correct answer...it displays the max attempt text output.

Comment: @user1752759, well, you have maxed out your attempts by then. I set the max attempts to 3 :) The number of `questions - 1`. I could have put the check for the correct answer first, but this way you prevent cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your code. The main issue you had was **mixing up your variable and function names**.

Here is a 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2r8pm5va/2/)

```
 <div class="question">
    <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
    <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">2</button>
    <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">5</button>
    <button class="rightAnswer" type="button">6</button>
    <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">10</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
<script>
var text;
var wrongAnswers = document.getElementsByClassName("wrongAnswer");
var rightAnswers = document.getElementsByClassName("rightAnswer");


for (var i = 0; i < wrongAnswers.length; i++) {
   // alert( wrongAnswers[i]);
    wrongAnswers[i].addEventListener('click', printWrongAnswer);
}
for (var i = 0; i < rightAnswers.length; i++) {
    rightAnswers[i].addEventListener('click', printRightAnswer);
}

function printRightAnswer() {
    text = "Correct!";
    printAnswer();
};
function printWrongAnswer() {
    text = "Incorrect!";
    text += "Wrong!";
    text += "Try Again!";
    printAnswer();
}
function printAnswer() {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = text;
}

</script>
```

Comment: This outputs all of the incorrect text responses at the same time.

Comment: Must have been the old fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code to help you understand how you could deal with `.getElementsByClassName`

```
 <div class="question">
 <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
      <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">2</button>
      <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button">5</button>
      <button class="rightAnswer" type="button">6</button>
      <button class="rightAnswer" type="button">10</button>
 </div>

 <div>
   <p id="answer">ok</p>
 </div>

   <script>
     var text="...",
     wrongs=document.getElementsByClassName("wrongAnswer"),
     rights=document.getElementsByClassName("rightAnswer"),
     wrongTexts=["Incorrect","Try Again","Wrong!"],
     i=0;

     for(var i=0; i< wrongs.length; i++){
           wrongs[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){ 
               text = "Incorrect!";
               DisplayText();
               });                  
     }
     for(var i=0; i< rights.length; i++){
           rights[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){ 
               text = "Correct!";
               DisplayText();
               });                   
     }
     function DisplayText(){
          i=i%wrongTexts.length;
          text=text=="Correct"?text:wrongTexts[i++];
           document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = text;
     }

   </script>
```

Comment: This outputs the same text response for the when the answer is wrong.

Comment: See my edited answer, You have an example in which wrong texts are alternated

Comment: Seems to now work with outputting the wrong answer using alternative responses, however...when the right answer is clicked, it displays the answer the same as the other buttons, incorrect.

Comment: The problem is the case sensitivity: so correct must starts with C and not c  `text=text=="correct"?text:wrongTexts[i++];`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers.. Here is another approach,

**HTML:**

```
<div class="question">
  <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button" onclick="checkAnswer(this)">2</button>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button" onclick="checkAnswer(this)">5</button>
  <button class="rightAnswer" type="button" onclick="checkAnswer(this)">6</button>
  <button class="wrongAnswer" type="button"  onclick="checkAnswer(this)">10</button>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
var count = 0;
var wrongtext = ["Incorrect!", "Wrong!", "Try Again!"]; 

function checkAnswer(el) {

    if (el.classList.contains('wrongAnswer')) {
       count++;

       if(count === 3)
          count = 0;

        alert(wrongtext[count])
    }
    if (el.classList.contains('rightAnswer')) {
        alert('correct');
     }
}
</script>
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/cubq361t/22/

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure how to make it so it will say different things like "wrong" and "incorrect" but I hope this will point you in the right direction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div class="section">
<p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
<input type="button" onClick="wrongAnswer()" value="2">
<input type="button" onClick="wrongAnswer()" value="5">
<input type="button" onClick="rightAnswer()" value="6">
<input type="button" onClick="wrongAnswer()" value="10">
<p id="text"></p>
</div>
<script>
function wrongAnswer() {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Wrong";
}
function rightAnswer() {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Correct!";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers of Mr. Polywhirl and Bellash:

If you are new to JavaScript you should try to understand how the EventBindings are working. Every binding in JavaScript is an event, so if you click somewhere the Browser will check if he will find a binding which is listening to the event "click". So its irrelevant when you bind the event but it has to be before the click. However you have to tell JavaScript which function he has to call if someone clicks your button! Thats because events are kinda "floating" in you browser scope, they are present but know one knows when they are actually be triggered but if they are getting triggered the script have to know what gets triggered or in other words: which functionality should be triggered now?

Your lines

```
var wrongAnswer = document.getElementsByClassName("wrongAnswer").addEventListener("click");
var rightAnswer = document.getElementsByClassName("rightAnswer").addEventListener("click");
```

are wrong because you never told the event "click" what functionality should be executed if the button is clicked.

The call or one type of a correct call would be:

```
var someFunction = function() { // DO YOUR AWESOME WORK PLS! }
var rightAnswer = document.getElementsByClassName("rightAnswer").addEventListener("click", someFunction);
```

and in addition to that:

I don't know how experienced you are in programming but this lines

```
 text = "Incorrect!";
 text = "Wrong!";
 text = "Try Again!";
```

will override each other, because you are using the same variable in all 3 rows ;)

Mr. Polywhirl and Bellash posted you some good example to begin with. Try them out and try to understand them!

Hope this makes it a bit clearer!

cheers,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rewrite of your code, providing comments as a sort of tutorial:

**Update**: added random response generation.

HTML:

```
<div class="question">
  <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>

  <!--
    Use a common class ('answer-button' used here) for all buttons
    so that clicks can be easily handled with a single listener.

    Since you know any answers that aren't right are wrong, you can
    simply add a 'right-answer' class for that one and leave the
    others as is.
  -->
  <button class="answer-button" type="button">2</button>
  <button class="answer-button" type="button">5</button>
  <button class="answer-button right-answer" type="button">6</button>
  <button class="answer-button" type="button">10</button>
</div>

<div>

  <!--
    Using an id is often unnecessary, so I'd switch this to a class.
    Since the above buttons represent answers, using an "answer" class
    on this paragraph can bring confusion, so I'd recommend using something
    more accurate, such as "response".
  -->
  <p class="response"></p>
</div>

<!--
  Generally you'll want your js in a separate file. If you include the script, whether
  inline or separate, at the bottom of the body element, as you did initially, it will
  automatically execute after the dom has initialized, which is good.
-->
```

JavaScript:

```
// Wrap in an immediately invoking function expression
// to keep your variables off the global scope.
(function() {

  // Capture all of your response phrases in an object.
  var responses = {
    correct: [
      "Correct!"
    ],
    incorrect: [
      "Wrong!",
      "Try Again!",
      "Incorrect!"
    ]
  };

  // Get the element that will display your answer.
  // getElementsByClassName returns an array, so get the
  // first element in the array.
  var response = document.getElementsByClassName('response')[0];

  // Get all of the answer buttons.
  var answerButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('answer-button');

  // Set a listener on each answerButton element.
  for (var i = 0; i < answerButtons.length; i++) {

    // Add the event listener to the element. When the event occurs,
    // the checkAnswer function will run, and will be passed an event object.
    answerButtons[i].addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
  }

  // event is an object that is automatically passed in
  // when the listener calls this function, and event.target
  // is the element where the event occurred.
  function checkAnswer(event) {

    // initialize a variable for the message
    var message;

    // get the element where the event occurred
    var element = event.target;

    // get all classes from target element
    var classes = event.target.className;

    // classes will be in a space-separated string, so
    // we convert that to an array
    classes = classes.split(' ');

    // check if a specific class is in the array
    if (classes.indexOf('right-answer') >= 0) {

      // if the 'right-answer' class is there, they
      // clicked the right answer.
      message = getRandomArrayElement(responses.correct);
    } else {

      // otherwise, they clicked the wrong answer
      message = getRandomArrayElement(responses.incorrect);
    }

    // set the target element's content to the message
    response.textContent = message;
  }

  function getRandomArrayElement(array) {
    // This function picks a random element from an array and
    // returns it.

    // You're going to want to pick one of these array items by their
    // index, so we'll set up variables to capture the lowest and
    // highest possible numbers that can be used.
    var min = 0;
    var max = array.length - 1;

    // Javascript provides random numbers using the Math.random function,
    // wich gives a random float between 0 and 1. The expression below
    // uses that to generate a random number within a given range - in this
    // case, between min and max.
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    return array[index];
  }
})();
```

Answer (score -3):

Make a function first and the assign it to the buttons like

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p class="demo"></p>
```

Then in the JS

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementByClassName("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

in your pen make a function add all the logic in it and call it on button click

Comment: You'd use `.getElements`??